How to use Pygame and Kivy
My question is not how to merge pygame and kivy screens. My problem is that I am working using kivy but in my code I added a function which runs a pygame program. When this program runs, the screen size remains the same as I defined it in the pyga code but all the items in the pygame screen shrink a bit in size and move a little bit top-left
Another problem is that when the both screens( kivy and pygame) run, they don't respond to click on the close button.


Here's some code

class Corrections(Screen):

    pass

class Correc(BoxLayout):

    def _init_(self,**kwargs):

        self.pp=open("corrections.txt","r")

        super()._init_(**kwargs)

        self.orientation="vertical"

        self.spacing=dp(5)

        self.pos_hint={"top":1}

        for i, line in enumerate(self.pp.readlines()):

            b = Button(text=line, size_hint=(.8, None), pos_hint={"x": .1}, height=(dp(40)),

                       on_press=lambda x:self.transit())

            self.add_widget(b)

    def opener(self, line):

        u = "C:\myown\computer\Assassin simulate" + line.rstrip("\n")+".pdf"

        u = u.rstrip('\n')

        os.startfile(u)


Kivy and pygame are not meant to work together. Both have to process events, but can't when running on the same thread. You could experiment with threads, but I think you should choose to use either of them. Also, how is your provided code related to the problem?

Sorry I forgot to add the function transit () defined in this same class
def transit(self):        Game().run()# this calls the pygame code

I have tried to use threading as you advised but I get a kind of deadlock situation on pygame screen, nothing displays on the screen and the cursor does not work on the screen

As far as I know, there is no official solution. If there even is one. Why exactly do you need to use both?

If you do have a function which run a pygame program the. You should -

Exit the kivy app.
Start the pygame app.
After the pygame program is finished restart the kivy app.

If you need to use pygame features such as rects, collision, etc, then import them directly without initializing the pygame.display.

How would I do that. Like which function will close the kivy out with out completely stopping the program

For the pygame part simply pause the code, as for the kivy part an exec statement might be able to resume your app.
